# Database-Independent to_char Function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, to-char

I am using SQLAlchemy to make database-independent querys.

I am facing one issue with `to_char` function.

Consider the simple query like:

```
select to_char(id,'999') from xyz
```

It's working on Postgres but MySQL doesn't support it.

How can I make this query database-independent using SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 3):

use the CAST function for simple type conversions.  it is SQL standard and SQLAlchemy supports it directly via the cast() function:  http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/sqlalchemy/expressions.html?highlight=cast#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast  .

for date values, SQLA has an extract() function that produces the SQL EXTRACT function - a translation layer translates common fieldnames like "month", "day", "minute", etc. into the appropriate keyword for the backend in use.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the cast function, for example**

```
cast(numberfield as char)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) in MySQL:

```
select format(id, '999') from xyz
```

To answer your all-in-one question: There's no cross-database way to do this. Every RDBMS is very different, and there's no real standardization past the fairly simple queries. This is especially true with string manipulations.

Comment: I agree .. to u .. i read some where that using sqlalchemy we can come over the difference. I tried but failed :(

Comment: @asb: You'll have to check which RDBMS you're using before making the call, sadly. This would either be in the function itself, or just use different functions with different engines.